# How to add a color or calibration bar

Tags: dm-script

I would like to append a color bar to my image to indicate what value corresponds to which color.
Something similar to the calibration bar in ImageJ.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the "Intensity bar".

Example script right from the F1 help documenation:

```c
image img := RealImage("Test",4,512,512)
img = itheta
img.ShowImage()
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

number kSCALEBAR = 31
number kINTENSITYBAR = 33

component scalebar = NewComponent( kSCALEBAR, 450, 100, 480, 300 )
disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd( scalebar )

component intbar = NewComponent( kINTENSITYBAR, 50, 400, 450, 490 )
disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd( intbar )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I work with GMS2, so I don't have these scripts in the help 
[Help screen][1]
I will look at the options of the intensity bar to see how I can get what I want.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbBsf.png

Comment: When I try to use the script, the intensity bar has a single grey color. It is just a uniform grey rectangle. And hen I look at the help topic for NewComponent, there is nothing corresponding to the value 33

Comment: @EricLeroy Did GMS 2 already have intensity bars? (as UI-enabled feature) I don't know when the feature was added exactly, but the script commands will (obviously) only work on versions from then on.  For GMS before that, you will have to create such a bar yourself. You can do that, by adding a different image (imageDisplay) as child-component onto the imageDisplay, just like you would add one image onto the other wiht copy&paste. However, this will be a "static" version, i..e if one changes contrast on the main image, that "bar" will not automatically update. I think there exists a script....

Comment: ...I think it was on the script database (https://www.felmi-zfe.at/dm-script/) but I can currently not access the site.

Comment: @EricLeroy I found the script, now that the page is online again. [Create Legendbar](https://www.felmi-zfe.at/dm_script/create-legend-bar?layout=blank)